# How to undo a git rebease action

Tags: git

**The situation is complicated.**

There have 2 branch, `feature` & `develop`

`feature` branch git log

```
* D
* E (feature checkout from develop)
```

`develop` branch git log

```
* H
* G
* F
* E
```

(1) in feature do => `git rebease develop`

it should be a merge action, rebease change the develop's commit info, git log as below, flag `-` means changed by rebease

```
* H -
* G -
* F -
* D
* E
```

(2) someone continue push to `feature` for a few days, git log looks like below

```
* A
* B
* H -
* G -
* F -
* D
* E
```

(3) one day, the feature developer make a pull request to develop branch

PR's change commits:

```
* A
* B
* H -
* G -
* F -
* D
```

it should be belows, cos rebease change the develop's commit H, G, F

```
* A
* B
* D
```

I want to undo the rebease action(1) make a merge but rebease, then redo the actions(2)

Is it possible to **fix** ????? Or just **accept**...

It make me couldn't review, cos H,G,F....total was over 100~~

Answer (score 2):

Likely you should revert to your previous state (see `git reflog`) and then re-apply rebase (check `git rebase -i` for *interactive* rebase when you can choose what commits to rebase and in which order)

Comment: :), year, fixed by  `git rebease -i `

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Actually, there're almost no mistakes with git commits which one couldn't fix [with some efforts]. The only fatal kind of mistakes is when you drop your content completely with `git reset` before storing the changes in the repo. And obviously keep copies of your repo at least in two independent locations.